# Method 'Method()' with Objective-C selector 'Method' conflicts with getter for 'Method' with the same Objective-C Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Since updating to Xcode 6.3 I've run into this on one of my extensions... for WKWebView.. Specifically on these functions.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

extension WKWebView: MyWebViewProvider {

    // Method 'URL()' with Objective-C selector 'URL' conflicts with getter for 'URL' with the same Objective-C Selector
    func URL() -> NSURL? {
        return self.URL
    }

    // Method 'canGoBack()' with Objective-C selector 'canGoBack' conflicts with getter for 'canGoBack' with the same Objective-C Selector
    func canGoBack() -> Bool {
        return self.canGoBack
    }

    // Method 'canGoForward()' with Objective-C selector 'canGoForward' conflicts with getter for 'canGoFoard' with the same Objective-C Selector
    func canGoForward() -> Bool {
        return self.canGoForward
    }

    // Method 'evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)' with Objective-C selector 'evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector
    func evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString: String!, completionHandler: (AnyObject, NSError) -> ()) {
        self.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString, completionHandler: { (AnyObject, NSError) -> Void in

        })
    }
}
```

How can I fix these? It was fine in 6.2.. bit of a pain.

Comment: change the method names ... of your extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the function name, or override those functions if that's what you want.

By the way, name conflicting should always be avoided. I suggest using something like `myURL`, `myCanGoBack()`.